# Spring DATA JPA onetoone unidirectional mapping CASCADE.ALL insert duplicate child row, not update

Tags: jpa, constraintviolationexception

I am writing an Entity class Result, and it has a ONETOONE mapping to another entity UpstreamResult.
When I do a save() method. In a spring boot concurrence situation, sometimes, the child entity get inserted not updated and throw  JdbcSQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Unique index or primary key violation

Parent Class:

```
@Table(name = "RESULT")
public class Result implements Serializable {

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    @JoinColumn(name = "UPSTREAMSIGNALTESTRESULT_ID", referencedColumnName = "uuid", unique=true)
    private UpStreamTestResult upStreamSignalTestResult;

  
    ...
```

Child Class:

```
@Table(name = "UPSTREAMTESTRESULT")
public class UpStreamTestResult implements Serializable {

    @Id
    private String uuid;

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (!(o instanceof UpStreamTestResult)) {
            return false;
        }

        UpStreamTestResult that = (UpStreamTestResult) o;

        if (this == that) {
            return true;
        }

        return this.getUuid().equals(that.getUuid());
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return this.getUuid().hashCode();
    }

.....
```

If I run my application once, it works fine. But when I  run my application aync and  high concurrance, , and all instance connect to one DB, it throw the above exception.

Comment: Could you add your services class here?

Comment: SSK, Thank you very much for your time. I already find the reason and fixed it.  God bless you!

Comment: Good to know you have find the solution, could you add it as answer so that others get help if they have ran into similar issue.